# Run module script before page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Here is my problem:
I want to redirect users away from this page if they are not logged in. Right now I'm using

```
<script text="javascript" type="module">
import { getLogInState } from './index.js';

redirectIfNotLoggedIn();

function redirectIfNotLoggedIn() {
    if (!getLogInState()) {
        window.location.replace("#landing");
    }
}
</script>
```

This imports a function from index.js which retrieves the value of 'loggedIn' from my Vue instance (I am using Vue.JS) only problem is that module type scripts are loaded after HTML so the user briefly (Or longer depending on their connection) sees the content of the page flash before they are brought back to the main page.

So I need to redirect the user if they are not logged into the page before the HTML is loaded, while also accessing an external function. Is this possible? My first idea was to just try calling the function in a separate non-module script since it's already imported by the module script but I don't know if that would actually work and if this script is loading before the rest of the page (and therefore the module) it doesn't matter.
Perhaps there is a better way of accessing Vue root, but I haven't been able to find it either way.

*Just to note my website is a SPA that works via jquery, hence the #links. This code is contained in a separate HTML file which is shoved into a 'content' div when you visit it. This shouldn't affect any potential answers but figured I might mention it.*

Comment: I think you don't need redirects. Possibly change the visibility/display of content by your login state.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there may be an easier way but it would be better just to do things that way, huh. They say you can never cut corners in web dev...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up adding a check to my router to not load the page if the user is not signed in, a much smarter solution that I came to after everything I read here, so thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [navigation guards from the router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Here is an abstract-ish code that you can use to concentrate the logic on the Vue Router

```
  Router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
        //Indetermined state of authentication
        // storeAuth.checkUserStatus automatically handles the is 
        if (isLogged() === null) await storeAuth.checkUserStatus();
        if (isLogged() === true) return next();
        if (!needsAuth(to)) return next();
        next({ name: 'login' });
    });
```

Hence, you can use custom functions to determine if a route needs auth or not.
One solution can be defining in the route's meta a "needsAuth" boolean.

So you can implement needsAuth like so:

```
const needsAuth = (route: Route): boolean => {
    return (route.meta.needsAuth) === true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I suppose I should have made it a little clearer, I'm just using some Jquery to route rather than using vue-router to keep things simpler and the actual loggedIn boolean is stored in my Vue instance which is instantiated by index.js This is the Jquery I'm using for routing.:

`$(window).on("hashchange", function () {  
  var page = window.location.hash;  
  console.log(page.substring(1));  
  $.get(page.substring(1) + ".html", function (pageContent) {  
    $("#content").html(pageContent);  
  });  
});`